# match statement not working in array/string search

Tags: powershell, okta

I am trying to create a routing to mirror our prod and prev environments.

I am having an issue with the -match function in powershell not working correctly.

I have the preview groups in an array called $PrevGroupInfo but when I try to search for the name of the prod group it doesn't match anything.  If I to the .profile.name search, it will return the name, but not the rest of the  info.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

```
Clear-host

$ProdSite = "https://logrhythm.okta.com"


$PrevSite = "https://logrhythm.oktapreview.com"

import-module OktaAPI

Connect-Okta $ProdToken $ProdSite

#Get Prod Users & Groups
$ProdGroupInfo = Invoke-Method GET "/api/v1/groups?limit=10000"
$ProdUserInfo = Invoke-Method GET "/api/v1/users?limit=10000"

Connect-Okta $PrevToken $PrevSite

#Get Prev Users & Groups
$PrevGroupInfo = Invoke-Method GET "/api/v1/groups?limit=10000"
$PrevUserInfo = Invoke-Method GET "/api/v1/users?limit=10000"

 ForEach ($Group in $ProdGroupInfo)
    {
        If ($Group.count -gt 0)
        {
            Connect-Okta $ProdToken $ProdSite

            #Get Group Members from Prod
            $Members = Get-OktaGroupMember $Group.id
            $GroupName = $Group.profile.name

            Connect-Okta $PrevToken $PrevSite
            $NewGroup = @()

            #***** Get Preview Group Name & ID
            If ($PrevGroup = $PrevgroupInfo -match $Group.profile.name)
            {
                $NewGroup += $PrevGroup
                Write-Host "Preview Group: " $NewGroup `t`t "ID: " $NewGroup.id -ForegroundColor DarkGreen
            }
            else 
            {
                Write-Host "Group not matched in Preview: " $Group.profile.name -ForegroundColor Red
            }

<#>            If ($Members -ne $null)
            {
                ForEach ($Item in $Members)
                {
                    Write-Host `t`t "Item: " $Item.profile.displayname `t`t "ID: " $Item.id
                }
                Pause
            }#>
        }
    }
```

I have tried just about everything my co-worked and I can come up with and both are stumped.

Answer (score 0):

To keep the full object back in `$PrevGroup`, filter with `Where-Object`, like:

```
If ($PrevGroup = $PrevgroupInfo | Where-Object {$_.profile.name -match $Group.profile.name})
```

If you expect the `name` property to be identical, then it's better to use `-like` or `-eq`:

```
$_.profile.name -like $Group.profile.name
```

Comment: Nice, but for conceptual clarity I suggest not mentioning `-like` for _equality_ comparisons, given that the sole reason for using `-like` is to match against [_wildcard expressions_](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Wildcards). Also worth mentioning that `-match` performs [_regex_](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Regular_Expressions) matching.

Comment: Thank you!  The where-object worked perfectly!